# what is a optimal setting for a sagemaker batch job?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Based on AWS documentation,  [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html), I've set up a batch inference job. however, once we choose the instance type and instance count, bare minimum , does sagemaker choose optimal plan to process jobs, say if there are more than one files , and if resource are available, can those files in parallel?

```
from sagemaker.transformer import Transformer

tr = Transformer(model_name='custom_model',instance_count=2, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

Answer (score 1):

Batch partitions the Amazon S3 objects in the input by key. Please checkout [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html)

When you have multiple input files to process, you can set the `BatchStrategy` to [MultiLine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html#sagemaker-CreateTransformJob-request-BatchStrategy) in order to speed up the processing.

General guideline is - number of workers/instances is a multiple of number of files in S3 to process.
If MaxConcurrentTransforms is set to 0 or left unset, Amazon SageMaker checks the optional execution-parameters to determine the settings for your chosen algorithm

Comment: thanks, could you elaborate a little more on the first point.  batch partitions help with parallel processing?

Comment: Let's say you have 10 different input files to be processed in the input S3 bucket. If you use set the number of workers to be 2 or a multiple of 2, then the input files are equally distributed across those instances. 
In addition if you set the `BatchStrategy` to be `MultiRecord`, each of the workers processes lines in the individual csv files as opposed to processing one line at the time( which is by default)

Comment: thanks . this is very helpful. when you say number of workers , are you referring to 'instance count' parameter? I noticed there is another parameter under "additional configuration', i.e. Max concurrent transforms. what about this parameter, so if you choose a multi core instance type , with instance count=1, can we set the max concurrent transforms to number of core in that instance type for parallel processing?